Gin cors middleware not working with Group()
When using gin-contrib/cors middleware directly in the default router, it works perfectly fine for any url, but when I create a group using r.Group("/api"), the cors does not apply to any of the route in that group.
When checking the response headers, I've found that when using group router, the 'access-control-allow-origin' is not set. I can still manually set the header and it works, but the cors middleware just seems to not be working at all.
But I've also tried to write my own middleware function to set 'access-control-allow-origin' header, and it also worked. So it seems like is the problem of the git-contrib/cors middleware:
func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.Header("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
        ctx.Next()
    }
}

If I just set all my routes on the default router, everything works flawlessly.
I've tried to set the middleware to the root router:
func main() {
        // other code
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.Default())
    apiRouter := r.Group("/api")

    apiRouter.GET("/record", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        // other code
    })
    r.Run("127.0.0.1:3000")
}

To the group router:
func main() {
        // other code

    r := gin.Default()
    apiRouter := r.Group("/api")
    apiRouter.Use(cors.Default())

    apiRouter.GET("/record", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        // other code
    })


    r.Run("127.0.0.1:3000")
}

or both, but all of them failed.
It works when the routes are set on the default router:
func main() {
        // other code
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.Default())

    r.GET("/api/record", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        // other code
    })
    r.Run("127.0.0.1:3000")
}

(btw, I've seen people talked about tailing '/' in group route before, but sadly it is not the cause of this problem)

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/3546#issuecomment-1657991662

It is a known problem: https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/issues/147

... to which there isn't really a good solution. Perhaps this is one more reason to opt for a different router, maybe even just stick with net/http (esp. since Go 1.22).

... to which there really isn't a good solution. Perhaps this is one more reason to opt for a different router, maybe even just stick with net/http (esp. since Go 1.22).
